# Refactor String concatenation to StringBuilder with intelliJ

Tags: string, intellij-idea, refactoring, stringbuilder

I was designated to make refactoring on a project, and  I came across this situation

```
 this.path = DESTINY + deploy.name() + FILE_SEPARATOR + delivery.getSystem().getCode()
      + FILE_SEPARATOR + delivery.getName() + FILE_SEPARATOR + delivery.getEnviroment().getName();
```

I want to refactor it to something like this:

```
StringBuilder tmpPath = new StringBuilder();
tmpPath.append(DESTINY);
tmpPath.append(deploy.name());
tmpPath.append(FILE_SEPARATOR);
tmpPath.append(delivery.getSystem().getCode());
tmpPath.append(FILE_SEPARATOR);
tmpPath.append(delivery.getName());
tmpPath.append(FILE_SEPARATOR);
tmpPath.append(delivery.getEnviroment().getName());
this.path = tmpPath.toString();
```

Or

```
StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

...

this.path.append(DESTINY);
this.path.append(deploy.name());
this.path.append(FILE_SEPARATOR);
this.path.append(delivery.getSystem().getCode());
this.path.append(FILE_SEPARATOR);
this.path.append(delivery.getName());
this.path.append(FILE_SEPARATOR);
this.path.append(delivery.getEnviroment().getName());
```

Whats is the fastest way to do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when having cursor on your original code:

[image]

Then you can choose the variant you prefer the most such as replacing it with String Builder. IDEA will do all the work for you.

[image]

Comment: I suspect the yellow highlight on `StringBuilder` after the refactor is IntelliJ recommending to replace the StringBuilder with String concatenation?

Comment: Yes, it may not be best to use stringbuilder unless in a cycle.