# How to replace all = with .add() in Android Studio

Tags: android, arrays, stringbuilder

I've come into many cases where I needed to change string concatenations to StringBuilder or Array to ArrayList.

I'm looking for a quick way to change my code from

```
myList[3] = "word"
```

to

```
myList.add("word")
```

Another example is from

```
sentence += " addon"
```

to

```
sentence.append(" addon")
```

Comment: android-studio supports regex replacement

Comment: yes that would work. Although I was really hoping for something as simple as an option in the refactor dropdown

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543138/refactor-string-concatenation-to-stringbuilder-with-intellij